# Create a completely new div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this is super easy I see a lot of answers for it. I want to make a completely new div using java script, and be able to give it a id and style it with css. I know I can use document.createElement but it does not doing anything for me. I set up a fiddle. can you please make it work, when I hit run it will make a new one. I don't need any explanation I can figure it out if i see it work once. I don't know why this is so hard to me.

```
div = document.createElement('div')
div.id = 'test'
#test{
 height: 46px;
width: 170px;
background-color: #23238e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/38rAy/embedded/result/

Comment: you need to add it back to document

Comment: jQuery: `$myDiv = $("<div />"); $(document.body).append($myDiv);`, apply your CSS rules: `$myDiv.css({"height":"46px", ... });` where it doesn't technically matter if you apply the css rule before or after appending, but before appending usually looks better in your final result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add that new div element to the document body.

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

To avoid confusion, you might want to name the variable something other than 'div'.

Comment: How come you have to call it .appendChild and not just append. Is it the Child of something?  I thought i was naming it with div.id = 'test'...even though i did  not see how it would know what div i am referring to if i had more then one.

Comment: HTML is a tree.  The `<html>` is the root node.  `<head>` and `<body>` and children of the the `<html>` node.  And `<html>` is considered the parent of the `<head>` and `<body>` nodes.  HTML is a deeply nested data format. And parent/child is the metaphor used to describe the structure of what is nested in what.  And the browser will only render elements that are children, or distant descendants, of `<body>`.

Comment: sorry i see. div = document.createElement('div')

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it to the document to see it:

```
div = document.createElement('div')
div.id = 'test'
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38rAy/1/

How else would the browser where the div exists in your page?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the node, it assigns it to the variable `div`, but it never gets added to the document.  You have to do something like

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "test";
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = div;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your creating the div but not ever  putting it on the page

you need to append the div by using document.body.appendChild or the code ive used here

http://jsfiddle.net/38rAy/2/

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];

body.appendChild(div);
```

if you want more flexibility than just appending to body

Comment: i'm a really new and know js on it's own and html on it's own. why would appending to body be more flexible. I guess i have to learn a lot more about DOM manipulation.

Comment: its not directly but specifing the tag is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert it into the DOM. Have a look at this method:

- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

You also need to have at least the body element. For example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'test';

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLdnn/).